# Allowing object creating of a class A from only a specific class B

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible in objectiveC to create an object of class A from class B. But, if any other class besides B try to create A, it shouldn't be able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange request. Why do you want to do this?

Off the top of my head, the clearest way I could think of to do this is to create an init method that takes self as a parameter, and check the class of the caller:

```
- (instanceType) initFromCaller: (id) caller
{
  if ([caller isKindOfClass: [TargetClass class])
    return nil;
  self = [super init]
  //Other init code here
}
```

Comment: Class A is  Singleton public class in iOS static framework. I want to expose it's public APIs, but want to make sure it's object is created from class B only which is in the same framework. Object of A shouldn't be directly created/accesed by framework user. A should be created in B and accessed through a property of B.

Comment: I would also: 1) add the following to disallow use of NSObject's default `-init`:  `- (instanceType)init { [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]; return nil; }`; 2) declare `-initFromCaller:` in a private category header on Object A that's only included in Object B's implementation (.m) file.